# Can a google map marker show a circular version of a square custom image as the icon?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I wonder if there is a away to show a circular version of a square image that is passed in as an icon image to a google map marker (api v3)?

Use case would be to show a round version of a gravatar as a marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon), you can specify the anchor, image and size of your marker icon, but you can't crop a circular version of it. I think you would want to store the gravatars as `.png` files and then crop them with transparency on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit the image when delivered from the server, maybe you can put a mask on it by adding another icon over the top of that same location with a transparent circular area in the center.

Although this may look a bit weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an HTML marker, give it
    border-radius:50%

and put an image in it.
You have a perfectly round image for marker.