# How can I style images used as markers in google map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to style the markers to be circular and stroked.

The icons I use are pictures of users

```
    for (var t = 0, llen = dub.length; t < llen; t++) {

        marker[t] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(dub[t]['lat'], dub[t]['long']),
          map: map,
          icon: dub[t]['m_avatar'],     //member pic
          title: dub[t]['title'],   //member name
          member_id: dub[t]['m_id']     //member ID
         // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP //add BOUNCE on hover
        });
}
```

right now it shows the images, I wish to make them circular and give them a stroke .

This is how I want the markers to appear

[image]

Comment: Did you check the [documentation about Marker images](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons)?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180724/can-a-google-map-marker-show-a-circular-version-of-a-square-custom-image-as-the

Comment: @manu79 That is exactly what I was looking for. I think adding another transparent icon over the image would solve the problem.